# Typescript Material UI Property 'classes' is missing in type for MUI component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Long story short, typescript complains the missing `property classes` on every material-ui component. In other words, **Typescript forces the `classes` property to be existed in almost every material-ui components**. Here is error message during webpack compiling using `ts-loader`,

I have following codes,

**Header.tsx**

```
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import * as React from 'react';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles/index';
import Toolbar from 'material-ui/Toolbar';
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';

const decorate = withStyles((theme) => ({
  header: {
    paddingTop: theme.spacing.unit,
    width: '100%',
  },
}));

const AppBarTypographyStyle = {
  color: 'white',
  fontSize: '1.6rem',
};

const Header = decorate(({classes}) => (
  <header>
    <AppBar position="static" classes={{root: classes.header}}>
      <Toolbar>
        <Typography style={AppBarTypographyStyle} classes={{}} color="inherit" type="title">
            OLIVE
        </Typography>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  </header>
));

export default Header;
```

And I have error for `Toolbar` with following messages

```
TS2322: Type '{ children: Element; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ToolbarProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Type '{ children: Element; }' is not assignable to type 'ToolbarProps'.
    Property 'classes' is missing in type '{ children: Element; }'
```

For `AppBar` and `Typography` I don't receive error as i added `classes property` with my styles defined in the `function decorator` and an empty object; However it is not possible to **JUST USE** `style & className properties`

```
<AppBar position="static" style={exampleStyleObj} className={exampleClass} >
```

I follows the styling approach using `withStyle` decorator from material-ui doc

> CSS IN JS & Over
> https://material-ui-next.com/customization/css-in-js/
>
> Overrides
> https://material-ui-next.com/customization/overrides/
>
> Typescript Material-UI guides
> https://material-ui-next.com/guides/typescript/

I am using,
typescript@2.4.0
material-ui@1.0.0-beta.21

I have checked if there are same issues and answer elsewhere and even checked the material-ui source codes and found the following,

```
/**
 * All standard components exposed by `material-ui` are `StyledComponents` with
 * certain `classes`, on which one can also set a top-level `className` and inline
 * `style`.
 */
export type StandardProps<C, ClassKey extends string, Removals extends keyof C = never> =
  & Omit<C & { classes: any }, 'classes' | Removals>
  & StyledComponentProps<ClassKey>
  & {
    className?: string;
    style?: Partial<React.CSSProperties>;
  }
```

The `StandardProps` is what most `ComponentProps interface` extends from (For example, AppBarProps). However so far i have not much luck for solving these.

Please help!

Comment: since you use Typescript, are u using this https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/material-ui ?

Comment: hey mate thanks for help! Unfortunately, @types/material-ui type definitions is for material-ui v0.18.17. Not for the V1 beta. In the V1 beta type definition has been added to the project itself at material-ui@next so no additional @types need to be installed.

However i edited my question based on what i found out, have a look!

Comment: @Ioala your example seems to work fine for me with `typescript@2.4.2` and `material-ui@1.0.0-beta.21`. What's more it should not be necessary as you say to provide an empty `classes` prop to any Material UI component... that was the case with some older versions of the typings, but not any more. Are you sure you're using the latest version?

Comment: @TomCrockett Hey man, it worked. I just upgraded my typescript from `typescript@2.4.0` to `typescript@2.4.2` and it successfully compile.

However i would like to hold this question a bit longer just in case similar error appears again down the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to answer my question. Thanks to [Tom Crockett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/231853/tom-crockett) from material-ui gitter.

Using Typescript `2.4.0` will not work due to the typing difference on material-ui components. However, `2.4.2` patch would fixes the problem.

Answer (score 5):

In TypeScript 4 there is now great support for Material UI's [**withStyle HOC**](https://typescript.tv/react/use-react-with-typescript/#Function-component-using-HOC-withStyles).

But you have export your component using `export default withStyles(styles)(YourComponent)` because otherwise TypeScript will still complain with:

> TS2741: Property 'classes' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Props'.

Here is a template which shows how it can be done using TypeScript 4:

```
import React from 'react';
import {createStyles, Theme, withStyles, WithStyles} from '@material-ui/core';

const styles = (theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    // ...
  });

interface Props extends WithStyles<typeof styles> {}

const YourComponent: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props): JSX.Element => {
  const {classes} = props;
  return (
    // ...
  );
};

export default withStyles(styles)(YourComponent);
```